# merge mutli dimensional arrays in VBA excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, merge

I have a very tough time with the redim function and the multi-dimensional arrays. I'm trying to merge two multi-dimensional arrays into one.  I know that the second dimension of each array will always be 2, but the first dimension will change.  When I use the redim function I do not get an error message but it erases everything that was in the first array in the first place.  When I use redim preserve I get a subscript out of range.  Help.

```
Function merge_arrays2(first_array As Variant, sec_array As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer

m = UBound(sec_array)
j = UBound(first_array)

ReDim first_array(m + j, 2)

For i = 1 To UBound(sec_array)
j = j + 1
first_array(j, 1) = sec_array(i, 1)
first_array(j, 2) = sec_array(i, 2)
Next

merge_arrays2 = first_array

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I solved the problem.

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, third_array(), m As Integer

m = UBound(sec_array)
j = UBound(first_array)

ReDim third_array(m + j, 2)

For i = 1 To UBound(first_array)
k = k + 1
third_array(k, 1) = first_array(i, 1)
third_array(k, 2) = first_array(i, 2)
Next

For i = 1 To UBound(sec_array)
k = k + 1
third_array(k, 1) = sec_array(i, 1)
third_array(k, 2) = sec_array(i, 2)
Next

merge_arrays2 = third_array
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following code. There were issues in Redimming and also in Function declaration

```
Sub test()

Dim a() As Variant
Dim b() As Variant
Dim c() As Variant


ReDim a(1, 2)
ReDim b(1, 2)
i = 0
Do While i < 2
    j = 0
    Do While j < 3
        a(i, j) = 1
        b(i, j) = 2
        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop

c() = merge_arrays2(a, b)

End Sub

Function merge_arrays2(first_array() As Variant, sec_array() As Variant) As Variant()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer

m = UBound(sec_array, 2)
n = UBound(first_array, 2)


ReDim Preserve first_array(1, m + n + 1)

For j = n + 1 To m + n + 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(sec_array, 1)
        first_array(i, j) = sec_array(i, j-n-1)
    Next
Next
merge_arrays2 = first_array

End Function
```

Comment: thanks for taking an interest in my problem and for the suggestions.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ReDim`, you are actually re-dimensioning the array without preserving its elements.
Using `Preserve` preserves the elements and thus solves the deleting of array elements.

The problem is, you  can only re-dimension the last dimension of the array and not the 1st one.
 And so you get the *Subscript Out of Range Error*. [See here MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx)

> Resizing with Preserve. If you use Preserve, you can resize only the last dimension of the array. For every other dimension, you must specify the bound of the existing array.

One way is what you've posted as answer and another way is below (for small arrays only):

```
Function merge2Darray(arr1, arr2) As Variant
    Dim tarr
    tarr = Application.Transpose(arr1)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
        ReDim Preserve tarr(1 To 2, 1 to UBound(tarr, 2) + 1)
        tarr(1, UBound(tarr, 2)) = arr2(i, 0)
        tarr(2, UBound(tarr, 2)) = arr2(i, 1)
    Next
    merge2Darray = Application.Transpose(tarr)
End Function
```

Take note that *Application.Transpose* Method have limitations.
You can only use it on small size arrays (a few thousand).